# SwiftUI Nullable NSMapGet

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, watchos

I'm trying to build and run a WatchOS application, but when the app runs it is showing me this error

> 2023-01-21 15:29:10.241806+0200 HealthKitApp Watch App[25909:4358527]
> void * _Nullable NSMapGet(NSMapTable * _Nonnull, const void *
> _Nullable): map table argument is NULL

I tried this for different devices(emulators) but the same issue

I ran this on Apple Watch Series 8,7, and 6 emulators

Comment: Could you please add the code where this error occurs and highlight exactly the line?